# How to let site member to access vertical tab?

Tags: 7, users

[image]

How to let site member access the picture above?

Comment: You can provide permission to that particular role which what to provide the access.

Comment: @NishantP I know about this. Question is which are the option i need to checked?

Comment: Ok. So provide the permission : 'Administer content permission' & 'Administer menus and menu items' to that particular role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which tab you're talking about. The highlighted one, **Menu settings**, is controlled by the *Administer menus and menu items* permission. Many of the vertical tab items is granted by the *Administer content* permission.